# How to cleanly regain the right coding system

Tags: emacs, iso-8859-1

Is there a way to have better conversion between unknown and known encodings?  Currently, many valid characters are incorrectly shown as not encodeable.

Here is the problem I had:

I open a Latin-1 textfile and to my surprise, the coding system indicator is no longer `1` but `=` meaning no-conversion.  All non-ascii characters show as escapes.
So I try to set the coding system right by m3 on the coding system indicator telling that I want to use Latin-1 again.

Now, all non-ascii characters that happen to be valid Latin-1 codes are listed as not being able to be encoded (which is actually incorrect). That is very confusing.

In the end, I solved the problem by discovering a zero-byte somewhere in the file.

To reproduce:

1. Open a valid Latin-1 file with non-ascii characters and note the `1:` as coding system indicator.
2. Add C-@ (zero) somewhere in it. Probably more in the beginning
3. Save the file and kill the buffer.
4. Now reopen that file,  and note that `=:` is the coding system indicator
5. Now switch to Latin-1 and see the buffer `*Warning*` showing you a list of the valid codes the system deems as inconvertible but not the one actual culprit since the list ends in ...

What I would expect is that only the zero-characters is shown.

(happens in Emacs 25 and 24 alike)

Answer (score 2):

`no-conversion` really means that the buffer is holding the underlying *raw bytes* rather than the intended characters.  And when you change the coding-system to latin-1 you're not changing the buffer's content, you're just telling Emacs that you intend to use latin-1 to *save* the buffer to the file.  So it complains about all the non-ASCII bytes because latin-1 does not know how to encode those *bytes* (it only encodes the chars that they are supposed to represent, i.e. it encodes them to those bytes).

What you want instead is to *reload* your file using the `latin-1` (instead of `no-conversion`) coding-system, which you can do with `C-x RET r latin-1 RET`.

Maybe Emacs should offer to the user to revert the buffer when the buffer is unmodified and you're changing from `no-conversion` to something else!  I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug` explaining how you found the interface confusing.